# Bootstrap With Google Web Fonts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I want my h1 text in the below example in `body` to use two different Google Web Fonts:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <h1 class="display-1 mt-5">This Is My Title</h1>
    <p class="lead mb-5">Coming Soon!</p>
</div>
```

I've created the following inline code in the header:

```
<!-- Google Web Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play|Sacramento" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Inline Style -->
<style>
    .logo-1:{
    font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
        }
    .logo-2:{
    font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
    }
</style>
```

How would I go about making "This Is" in Play Font & "My Title" in the Sacramento font?

Comment: Note: I'm mentioning the use of Bootstrap in the view that there may be an easier way of doing the above & to explain the other codes in the class which may otherwise clash.  I accept that otherwise this is a simple html / css question.

Comment: Your CSS has errors. There should not be a colon after your class name(s) **.logo-1:{}**: `.logo-1 { font-family: 'Play', sans-serif; }` and `.logo-2 { font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `span` element, which allows you to add styles without affecting the layout & positioning because `span` is an inline element.

```
<h1 class="display-1 mt-5">
  <span class="logo-1">This Is </span>
  <span class="logo-2">My Title</span>
</h1>
```